# Tkinter bind for <Command--> exception

Tags: tkinter, key, bind

It seems I cannot bind the keystroke `<Command-->`. This raises an `_tkinter.TclError: no event type or button # or keysym` exception.  It seems like that should work given that `<Command-+>` and `<Command-_>` work fine. Two questions:

1. where do/should I report this bug?
2. what is a practical workaround in the interim?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a bug, it's just how tkinter works. To bind to the command-minus key use `<Command-minus>`.